# How to perform incremental refresh on table that is used as base for star schema modelling?

Tags: powerbi

Incremental refresh concept is pretty straight-forward if individual tables are being incrementally loaded. Following are 2 scenarios where-in a star schema is created (explained below).

In **scenario 1** - Star schema is created from 1 table.

In **scenario 2** - Star schema is created from Union of 2 tables.

**Is it possible to implement incremental refresh in these scenarios and how?**

**Scenario 1**:

In transform window I have tblA is a denormalized table. Assuming I make a star schema from this table, by doing the following for each dimension: duplicating the tblA, remove unnecessary columns, remove duplicate rows, add index column.

Finally merge each dimension table with the tblA to bring in the respective ID and remove the name column(s) from the tblA.

How to implement incremental refresh in this scenario?

**Scenario 2**:

In Transform window, I have created queries for 2 tables (tblA and tblB)

Then I have used union to combine the both tables into new 3rd table (tblC)

From this 3rd table I have created star schema model as 4 dimension and 1 fact table.

There is large amount of data resulting in slow refresh time and load on source SQL Server db.

How to implement incremental refresh in this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't even load tblA and tblB into the model, so you *must* configure incremental refresh on tblC.

To do this the Power Query for tblC must include the RangeStart and RangeEnd parameters.  These parameters may *also* be used directly in the queries for tblA and tblB.

To derive dimensions from the same table, just reference the base table multiple times.  Once with RangeStart/RangeEnd and once for each dimension.

eg, bring in FactInternetSales, and turn off Loading on that query and reference it twice.  First as SalesFact:

```
let
    Source = FactInternetSales,
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each [OrderDateKey] >= Date.Year(RangeStart)* 10000 + Date.Month(RangeStart)* 100 * Date.Day(RangeStart)),
    #"Filtered Rows1" = Table.SelectRows(#"Filtered Rows", each [OrderDateKey] <  Date.Year(RangeEnd)* 10000 + Date.Month(RangeEnd)* 100 * Date.Day(RangeEnd))
in
    #"Filtered Rows1"
```

and once in DimProduct

```
let
    Source = FactInternetSales,
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(Source,{"ProductKey"}),
    #"Removed Duplicates" = Table.Distinct(#"Removed Other Columns"),
    #"Inserted Merged Column" = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Duplicates", "ProductName", each Text.Combine({"Product", Text.From([ProductKey], "en-US")}), type text)
in
     #"Inserted Merged Column"
```

Then the dimensions will be fully refreshed every time and the fact will be incrementally refreshed.

Comment: From tblC I have created 4 dim tables, and tblC is my fact table. So if I apply incremental refresh to tblC then will it automatically refresh data for 4 dim tables as well?

Comment: Are the dim tables DAX calculated tables, or Power Queries?

Comment: They are power query

Comment: If they reference the base table directly without the RangeStart/RangeEnd parameters they will be reloaded on each refresh.

Comment: So do I need to apply incremental refresh on tblC or the dimension tables created from tblC?

Comment: I doubt you want incremental refresh on the dimension tables.

Comment: The thing is that the dimension tables are created from tblC (by duplicating the tblC, removing additional columns, keeping distinct values, adding index col, merging with original tblC). Can you guide me with this. Is it possible to implement incremental refresh in this scenario?